# Backbone js append replaces html instead of appending element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I am a beginner at backbone.js . I started creating a small todo application with examples from Addy Yosmani's "Backbone fundamentals" . I have sample code as below. I used a view for each item and I have a list view wherein I render each item and append it to the list but instead of appending it replaces the whole thing. I tried with a debugger and the element stays with the first todo after the loop ran for the first time but in the second run the element gets replaced instead of appending. I couldn't figure out a solution for this.

code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Hello World in Backbone.js</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.0/backbone.localStorage-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="my-container">
        </div>

        <div class="container container-fluid" id="container" style="margin-top:5px;">
        </div>

        <script type="text/template" id="item-template">
            <div class="post-panel" style="margin-top:5px;">
                <div class="panel-default panel-heading post-title">
                    <%= title %>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-default panel-body post-content">
                    <%= content %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </script>

        <script>
         var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend();

         var TodoItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

             todo_tpl: _.template($('#item-template').html()),

             el: $('#container'),

             render: function() {
                 this.$el.html(this.todo_tpl(this.model.attributes));
                 return this;
             },
         });

         var TodoListView = Backbone.View.extend({

             el: $('#my-container'),

             render: function() {

                 posts = [
                     {'title': 'sample title 1' , 'content': 'sample content 1'},
                     {'title': 'sample title 2' , 'content': 'sample content 2'},
                     {'title': 'sample title 3' , 'content': 'sample content 3'},
                     {'title': 'sample title 4' , 'content': 'sample content 4'},
                 ];

                 for (i=0; i < posts.length; i++) {
                     var todo1 = new Todo(posts[i]);
                     var todo1_view = new TodoItemView({model: todo1});
                     this.$el.append(todo1_view.render().el);
                 }
                 return this;
             },

         });


         var todo1 = new Todo({"title" : "sample title" , "content" : "sample content"});
         var todo1_view = new TodoItemView({model: todo1});
         var todo_list_view = new TodoListView();
         todo_list_view.render()
             //         todo1_view.render();

        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: All of the ItemView point to the same element `$('#container')`. So your code is keep overwriting the content in `$('#container')`, and append it to `$('#my-container')`.

Comment: @fuyushimoya Thanks. I just commented it out and I get to render the elements. How could I create four elements of container class?

Comment: @fuyushimoya Since you said its appending the newly created content along with the div `my-container` why is it replacing?

Comment: Because all 4 item use the same element `$('#container')`, and repeat appending `$('#container')` to `$('#my-container')` won't have any effect, because its already in `$('#my-container')`.

Comment: @fuyushimoya How could I create four elements of container class? The code in the below answer creates four divs and appends them inside the `my-container`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Backbone.View.el](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el):

> `this.el` can be resolved from a DOM selector string or an Element;
>   otherwise it will be created from the view's `tagName`, `className`, `id`
>   and `attributes` properties. **If none are set, this.el is an empty div,
>   which is often just fine.** An el reference may also be passed in to the
>   view's constructor.

So you can either simply add an option setting:

```
className: 'container container-fluid'
```

or you also want to preserve that `style="margin-top:5px;"`

```
attributes: {
    className: 'container container-fluid',
    style: 'margin-top:5px;'
}
```

Below demos the `tagName` way, you can see attributes way [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6nnd13t0/3/).

```js
         var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend();

         var TodoItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

           todo_tpl: _.template($('#item-template').html()),

           // Give the created element classes
           className: 'container container-fluid',

           // Backbone default creates an empty div if you don't specifiy
           // tagName: 'div',

           render: function() {
             this.$el.html(this.todo_tpl(this.model.attributes));
             return this;
           },
         });

         var TodoListView = Backbone.View.extend({

           el: $('#my-container'),

           render: function() {

             posts = [{
               'title': 'sample title 1',
               'content': 'sample content 1'
             }, {
               'title': 'sample title 2',
               'content': 'sample content 2'
             }, {
               'title': 'sample title 3',
               'content': 'sample content 3'
             }, {
               'title': 'sample title 4',
               'content': 'sample content 4'
             }, ];

             for (i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
               var todo1 = new Todo(posts[i]);
               var todo1_view = new TodoItemView({
                 model: todo1
               });
               this.$el.append(todo1_view.render().el);
             }
             return this;
           },

         });


         var todo1 = new Todo({
           "title": "sample title",
           "content": "sample content"
         });
         var todo1_view = new TodoItemView({
           model: todo1
         });
         var todo_list_view = new TodoListView();
         todo_list_view.render()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.3/backbone-min.js"></script>

<div id="my-container">
</div>

<div class="container container-fluid" id="container" style="margin-top:5px;">
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="item-template">
  <div class="post-panel" style="margin-top:5px;">
    <div class="panel-default panel-heading post-title">
      <%=title %>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-default panel-body post-content">
      <%=content %>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This sums up the whole thing for me that I asked in the comments.

Comment: I've also add another way use `attributes` on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nnd13t0/3/), you can see if that suit you more, as your original div has that style, also the ref of [Backbone.View.attributes](http://backbonejs.org/#View-attributes). :)

Comment: Thanks :) I am beginner in Javascript too. I din't know that appending the same DOM element again will not append it. More learning :) I was appending it a string in the day and now I wonder the difference between appending the same DOM element and appending it as a string to the append method.

Comment: When you append a `string`, jQuery assume its a [htmlString](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#htmlString) an tries to use it to create a jquery object that contains the dom elemsnts parse by jquery, so it'll create new element each time instead of append the same dom element.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, currently you are calling `TodoItemView` for each post, and inside `TodoItemView` you are saying:

```
this.$el.html(this.todo_tpl(this.model.attributes));
```

Which is the reason it will only show the *last* post (it keeps replacing the posts). Since there are multiple `TodoItemView`'s you need to change this line to use `append`:

```
this.$el.append(this.todo_tpl(this.model.attributes));
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6nnd13t0/)

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't `return this` at the end return the object and then the element is appended to the `TodoListView` el. So shall I remove the list view? I don't get the point. why does interchanging the `append` and `html` not working?